# ReadDirectoryChangesW returns some of the directories with a different case

Tags: winapi, filestream

I am using `ReadDirectoryChangesW` to watch a directory. I recently discovered that in some cases (on Windows 7) the path to the file that I am receiving has some of the directories with a different cases (they were uppercased) than what I see in the folder explorer. I suspect that it might be related to this line part of the `ReadDirectoryChangesW` documentation:

> If you opened the file using the short name, you can receive change notifications for the short name.

I assume that in same cases when the long path (that I am using) matches the short path for the same directory the API is confused.

In my scenario - receiving the original cases is important.

My question is - is there a way to force ReadDirectoryChangesW to stick with the cases the files appear in file explorer (the original cases) when it reports the paths.

Comment: How old is this operating system?  [This might match](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.08.windowsconfidential.aspx).

Comment: Windows 7. This is very legitimate guess, but I will say it is not the case. Other API's I tried to obtain the name for example: dir from command line or FindFirstFileW, return the name that I expect (lowercased).

Answer (score 1):

I confirmed my suspicion. ReadDirectoryChangesW is reporting short paths. The reason this is happening in this particular case was that the directory path was finishing to a directory with uppercased name: `c:\foo\BAR`. This was misinterpreted that the supplied path is short path. To workaround it, I just lower case whatever the input is when I create the handle and this eliminates the misinterpretation.

Note: that this does not help if the app that has activity over the file uses short path - the notification will still be short. Thanks, @HarryJohnston

Comment: I don't believe there's any guarantee that notifications will arrive in any particular case - they might, for example, appear with the case that the other application (the one making the change) used.  That is, short paths are not the only possible cause.